# Fine-tuning a BERT model without answers

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I come here after I have been googling during many hours for to know if it's was possible to make a fine-tune `BERT` Question Answering with only question and context ? I am beginner with BERT model so I don't know the deep mechanism that it have even after many search. Thanks you for your answer

Comment: What will be the purpose of such a fine-tuned model?

Comment: The purpose is to create a financial QA only for testing

Comment: You can't train an extractive QA model without answers. Maybe use a foundation model to create some answers and use those as targets. In case the actual answer doesn't matter, you could also train it with random answers.

Comment: What is the final purpose of selecting random answers that doesn't answer the question ?

Comment: Well, you wrote that you train it only for testing. Since I am unaware of what kind of testing you want to perform, I suggested random answers to test the pipeline (coding part). This is of course useless for the performance part (i.e. if the model produces useful results).